# Sorting ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sorting, observablecollection

Suppose I have `ObservableCollection` of employee class

```
public ObservableCollection<Employee> employeeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Employee() {}
}
```

now I am trying to sort the `ObservableCollection` (“employeeCollection”) 
by appropriate selection by user from combobox[it will be….Sort By FirstName….Sort By MobileNumber etc…]..

and it is required to **get back sorted observable collection….**
Means it **should not be in form of “var” it should be 
`ObservableCollection<Employee>`**

So I can assign back it to `“ItemsSource”` property of `“ItemsControl”`…

Thanks……

Comment: Why do you want to sort the collection? You can also perform the sorting on the data binding.

Comment: [In my applicaton “Item controle” display each employee in observable collection now I want to sort observable collection so UI of my application  will change as per  observable collection will be sorted……thanks]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can sort the view of the collection rather that sorting the collection itself:

```
// xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
<myView.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemListViewSource" Source="{Binding Itemlist}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SortingProperty" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</myView.Resources>
```

And then you can use the CollectionViewSource as ItemSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemListViewSource}}"
```

Comment: Note that `PropertyName` can't use binding. It directly results in the following run-time error: `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'PropertyName' property of type 'SortDescription'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Is this new behaviour? I could swear I used it that way. But I do not have access to the code anymore to check it.

Comment: @Well, it's not highly propable that you used it that way. The property is after all called `PropertyName` which indicates that it could take a string name of a property, not a direct binding to it. But I'm new to WPF, I only stumbled across this because I was searching for the solution and I implemented it, so it's maybe possible that it worked the other way before.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Anyway... Thanks for the edit.

Comment: How can I do this descending?

Comment: @devjme https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.sortdescription?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: awesome thx!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think PVitt may have the best solution... however, i did find this 
SortedObservableCollection class that perhaps could help?

http://softcollections.codeplex.com/

Comment: An alternative implementation of a sorted observable collection: [ObservableSortedList<T>](https://bitbucket.org/rstarkov/wpfcrutches/src/tip/ObservableSortedList.cs).

Comment: Codeplex link is broken

Answer (score 2):

I implemented an `ObservableCollectionView` which supports sorting and filtering using a lambda (like LINQ but live) and item tracking:

https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObservableCollectionView

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort yourself, but can let WPF do it for you. See [SortDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.aspx), for example.